Entites are not rendering
I stuck in the problem that my entites are not showing. I found Entities graphic rendering sample for runtime it perfectly worked. But when i am integrating its code, there is no luck. Please tell me what i am doing wrong.
public class EntityRendering : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject prefab; // Reference to the traditional prefab
    public Material entityMaterial; // Material to be used for entities
    public int objectCount = 10000;

    private EntityManager entityManager;
    private EntityArchetype entityArchetype;

    void Start()
    {
        entityManager = World.DefaultGameObjectInjectionWorld.EntityManager;

        // Define the components that entities will have
        entityArchetype = entityManager.CreateArchetype(
            typeof(RenderMesh),
            typeof(LocalToWorld),
            typeof(ComponentTranslatoin),
            typeof(ComponentRotation),
            typeof(ComponentScale),
            typeof(ComponentMoveSpeed)
        );

        // Create entities
        for (int i = 0; i < objectCount; i++)
        {
            Entity entity = entityManager.CreateEntity(entityArchetype);

            // Assign a mesh and material to the entity
            entityManager.SetSharedComponentManaged(entity, new RenderMesh
            {
                mesh = prefab.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh,
                material = entityMaterial
            });

            // Set initial position, rotation, and scale
            entityManager.SetComponentData(entity, new ComponentTranslatoin
            {
                value = UnityEngine.Random.insideUnitSphere * 10
            });

            entityManager.SetComponentData(entity, new ComponentRotation
            {
                value = quaternion.identity
            });

            entityManager.SetComponentData(entity, new ComponentScale
            {
                value = new float3(1f, 1f, 1f)
            });

            entityManager.SetComponentData(entity, new ComponentMoveSpeed
            {
                value = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1f, 3f)
            });

            var renderMeshArray = new RenderMeshArray(new Material[] { entityMaterial }, new Mesh[] { prefab.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh });
            var desc = new RenderMeshDescription(
                shadowCastingMode: ShadowCastingMode.Off,
                receiveShadows: false);
            RenderMeshUtility.AddComponents(entity, entityManager, desc, renderMeshArray, 
                MaterialMeshInfo.FromRenderMeshArrayIndices(0, 0));

        }
    }

I checked that entites are creating in entities/hirachy but not showing/rendering

Please walk us through the steps to create a project from scratch that demonstrates this problem. This should cover what project template or packages you've used, presumably including the Entities Graphics package.

It is a small project is already on the githhub (https://github.com/MuhammadFaizanKhan/DOTSvsTraditionalUnity).

The project is on URP with Entites and entity graphic Package.

Most people will not download a full project off GitHub in order to try to answer a question. Your Minimal Complete Verifiable Example should fit inside the question itself.
